# Animation Keyframes no Fading?

Tags: css, animation, transition, keyframe

```
@keyframes test {

   0% { color: red;   } /* Starts red */
  50% { color: green; } /* Fades to green from red */
 100% { color: blue;  } /* Instant blue? Is no fading from green possible? */

}
```

Is it possible to have 0% - 50% transition normally from `red` to `green`, and then have `blue` appear instantaneously after with no transition? So in the example above, once 50% is complete, it immediately becomes `blue` (i.e. without fading in from green) until 100% is done?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xfsa/4/) works ok

```
<div class="top"></div>

.top {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: test 5s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0%   { background:red; }
  50%  { background:green; }
  50.01%  { background:blue; }
  100%  { background:blue; }
}
```

Comment: Blue needs to appear without fading in from green.

Comment: The 1% workaround is a good, but still need a way to instantly become blue without the smallest delay.

Comment: try the fiddle again please

Comment: I voted up for this being a good practical solution. But I wonder if there is still a technical way.